# X is Hausdorff iff a net converges to at most one point

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I wrote proof to following theorem. I ask for verification of my reasoning.

*Theorem 3* from General Topology by Kelley:

> A topological space is a Hausdorff space if and only if each net in the space converges to at most one point.

**Proof**
"$\Rightarrow$" Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Hausdorff space. For any points $x,y$ of topology $\tau$ there are $Z,W\in \tau\quad$  s.t.
$x\in Z $ and $y\in W$, and $Z\cap W \in \tau$. Hence there is a net $S_n$ in $X$ directed by $\subset$.

Since $X$ is a Hausdorff space, there are neighborhoods $U,V$ in base of the space s.t
$x\in U \subset Z$,
$y\in V\subset W$, and $U\cap V = \emptyset$.
So if $S_n$ converges to both $x$ and $y$, it is eventually in $U$ and $V$, which are disjoint. Therefore $S_n$ can converge to one point at most.

"$\Leftarrow$" Let each net $S_n$ converge to at most one point in the space $X$.
Suppose that $S_n$ converges to both $x$ and $y$.
Then $S_n$ is eventually in both neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$. Hence there are neighborhoods of two points which are not disjoint. So $X$ is not a Hausdorff space.

*Is following conclusion valid, to complete the proof?*

Therefore if $S_n$ converges to at most one point in $X$, it is a Hausdorff space.

Comment: On the backwards direction, you first suppose that each net converges to at most one point, but then immediately after suppose that a net converges to both $x$ and $y$. Which seems contradictory to me. Also, for any two points, there always exist overlapping neighbourhoods of both points, even in a Hausdorff space (for example, in a metric space, take the open ball with radius $d(x,y)$ around each point). The existence of such neighbourhoods therefore cannot disprove the space being Hausdorff.

Comment: @celt I was thinking of proof by contradiction in <=. The assumption here is that the net converges to both points, which means that it is in every neighborhood of each point eventually. Which means that no two neighborhoods of the points are disjoint, therefore they cannot be in Hausdorff space by definition.

Comment: In a proof of contradiction you assume the contrary of the *consequent*, which in the backwards direction is that $(X,\tau)$ is a Hausdorff space. That is, you would have had to assume that it is not a Hausdorff space and derive a contradiction from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you have the right ideas but your proof needs a bit of cleaning.

Here is a sketch that may help you clean your proof:

---

for any $x\in X$, denote by $\mathcal{V}_x$ the collection of open sets containing $x$.

Suppose $X$ is a topological space where each convergent net has a unique limit. If $X$ were not Hausdorff, then there would exist a pair of points $x$ and $y$ such that for any open sets $V\in\mathcal{V}_x$ and $U\in\mathcal{V}_y$  there is $x_{U,V}\in V\cap U$.  Then  $\{x_{V,U}:(V,U)\in\mathcal{V}_x\times\mathcal{V}_y\}$ is a net in $X$ (why?) that converges to both $x$ and $y$ which is a contradiction.

Conversely, suppose $X$ is Hausdorff and $\{x_n:n\in D\}$ is net converging to $x$ and $y$. If $x\neq y$, let $V_x$ and $V_y$ be disjoint open neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively. There is $m\in D$ such that $x_n\in V_x$ and $x_n\in V_y$ for all $n\geq m$. This is a contradiction to $V_x\cap V_y=\emptyset$.

Comment: I suppose that the relation in $\mathcal{V}_x\times\mathcal{V}_y$ is defined through the condiction $$(V_1,U_1)\le (V_2,U_2)\overset{def.}\Leftrightarrow V_2\subseteq V_1\,\wedge\,U_2\subseteq U_1$$ for any $(V_1,U_2),(V_2,U_2)\in\mathcal{V}_x\times\mathcal{V}_y$ so that we can claim that $\mathcal{V}_x\times\mathcal{V}_y$ is a directed set, right? So if for any $(V,U)\in\mathcal{V}_x\times\mathcal{V}_y$ we pick an element $x_{V,U}$ then we make a net.

Comment: @OliverDiaz The set $\{x_{V,U} : (V,U)\in \mathcal V_x \times \mathcal V_y \}$ is a net in $X$ because any $x_{V,U}$ is in intersection of two subsets:  
$x_{V,U} \in V \cap U \subset \mathcal V_x \cap \mathcal V_y$.  
Thus $V \cap U$ is directed by $\subset$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is substantially correct: to follow (I hope you like it) I rewrite it with some additional words so that it could must more clear.

**Theorem**

A topological space $X$ is hausdorff if and only if any net $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ converges at most one point $x$.

*Proof*. So let be $X$ is hausdorff and we suppose that $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a net converging to the distinct point $x$ and $y$. So if $X$ is hausdroff and if $x$ and $y$ are different point of $X$ then there exist two open and disjoint sets $U_x$ and $U_y$ containing respectively $x$ and $y$ so that if $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$  converges to $x$ and $y$ then tere exist $\lambda_x,\lambda_y\in\Lambda$ such that $x_\lambda\in\ U_x$ for any $\lambda\ge\lambda_x$ and $x_\lambda\in U_y$ for any $\lambda\ge\lambda_y$ and so for $\lambda_{xy}\in\Lambda$ such that $\lambda_{xy}\ge\lambda_x,\lambda_y$ (remember that $\Lambda$ is a directed set) it follows that $x_\lambda\in U_x\cap U_y$ for any $\lambda\ge\lambda_{xy}$ and clearly by the definition of $U_x$ and $U_y$ this is impossible.

Now we suppose that there exist a net $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ in $X$ converging to two different points $x$ and $y$ so that through the same argument promoted above it folows that there exist a $\lambda_0\in\Lambda$ such that $x_\lambda\in U_x\cap U_y$ for **any** open neighborhood $U_x$ and $U_y$ of $x$ and $y$ and so clearly $X$ is not hausdorff. So we conclude that if any net $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ in $X$ converges at most one point then $X$ is hausdorff.