# Is the derivative of a complex function uniquely determined?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, nets

**Definition**

A complex function $f:\Omega\rightarrow\Bbb C$ defined in a open set $\Omega$ of $\Bbb C$ is said derivable at $z_0$ if the limit
$$
\frac{df}{dz}(z_0):=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}h
$$
exist.

Now we observe that if $\phi$ is the natural homeomorphism between $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb C$ then
$$
f(z)=\dots=\operatorname{Re}{f(z)}+\operatorname{Im}{f(z)}\cdot i=\operatorname{Re}{f(\operatorname{Re}z+\operatorname{Im}z\cdot i)}+\operatorname{Im}{f(\operatorname{Re}z+\operatorname{Im}z\cdot i)}\cdot i=\\\operatorname{Re}{f\big(\phi(\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Im}z)\big)}+\operatorname{Im}{f\big(\phi(\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Im}z)\big)}\cdot i
$$
for any $z\in\Omega$ so that putting
$$
\begin{cases}u(x,y):=\operatorname{Re}{f\big(\phi(x,y)\big)}\\v(x,y):=\operatorname{Im}{f\big(\phi(x,y)\big)}\end{cases}
$$
for any $x,y\in\phi^{-1}[\Omega]$ then we conclud that
$$
f(z)=\dots=\operatorname{Re}{f\big(\phi(\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Im}z)\big)}+\operatorname{Im}{f\big(\phi(\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Im}z)\big)}\cdot i=\\
u(\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Im}z)+v(\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Im}z)\cdot i=u\big(\phi^{-1}(z)\big)+v\big(\phi^{-1}(z)\big)\cdot i
$$
for any $z\in\Omega$ or equivaletely
$$
\phi(x+y\cdot i)=f\big(\phi(x,y)\big)=u\Big(\phi^{-1}\big(\phi(x,y)\big)\Big)+v\Big(\phi^{-1}\big(\phi(x,y)\big)\Big)\cdot i=u(x,y)+v(x,y)\cdot i
$$
for any $(x,y)\in\phi^{-1}[\Omega]$. Now if the above limit was not path dependent then it would be
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\cdot i=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\big(u(x+h,y)+v(x+h,y)\cdot i\big)-\big(u(x,y).v(x,y)\cdot i\big)}{h}=\\
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\big((x+h)+y\cdot i\big)-f(x+y\cdot i)}h=\frac{df}{dz}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\big(x+(y+h)\cdot i\big)-f(x+y\cdot i)}{h\cdot i}=
\\\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\big(u(x,y+h)+v(x,y+h)\cdot i\big)-\big(u(x,y)+v(x,y)\cdot i\big)}{h\cdot i}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{1}i\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdot i
$$
that would implies the Cauchy-Riemann identities
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
$$
but unfortunately I am not able to prove that the limit $\frac{df}{dz}(z_0)$ is uniquely determined. In particular I know that $\Bbb C$ is a hausdorff space so that any net $(h_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ has at least one limit but I am not able to understand why this implies that if $(h_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ and $(k_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ are two distinct nets converging to $0$ then it must be $$
\lim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\frac{f(z+h_\lambda)-f(z)}{h_\lambda}=\lim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\frac{f(z+k_\lambda)-f(z)}{k_\lambda}
$$
provided that the two limt exist. Another possible solution is to define the function
$$
\varphi(h):=\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}h
$$
and so use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889547/the-uniqueness-of-a-limit-of-a-function-spivaks-proof) relevant result but unfortunately the function $\varphi$ is not defined at $0$ and so it is not possible to use the linked theorem -e.g. the limit of the function $\frac x{|x|}$ does not exist when $x$ approaches to zero and it is not definet at zero!!! So could someone help me, please?

Comment: First of all: I'm not sure why you even bother with nets when we are inside metric world. Just use sequences. Secondly: the existence (and thus uniqueness because of Hausdorff) of the limit follows from the definition of complex derivative. It is an assumption.

Comment: "I know that $\mathbb{C}$ is a Hausdorff space so that any net has at least one limit." The truth is, in a Hausdorff space the limit is unique if it exists. So the question of uniqueness is automatically resolved by the Hausdorff separation property. The property you mentioned (that any net has at least one limit point) is rather that of a compact space. Of course, $\mathbb{C}$ is not compact.

Comment: Why would you talk about nets and stuff when we're only in the complex plane?? In the complex plane, if a function $\phi$ has a limit, it must be unique. Also, Spivak doesn't require functions to be defined at the point where you're considering limits. Look carefully at the argument there; everything works for complex numbers, and we're using punctured neighborhoods $0<|z-a|<\delta$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Okay, now I understood: moreover the Spivak theorem can be extended to  a general metric space, right?

Comment: yes metric spaces too. Also, as others have mentioned, in Hausdorff spaces, if limits exist, they're unique (you don't even need nets for this). But you're in the complex plane, so there's no need to use nuclear bombs to deal with minor issues.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition**

If $X$ and $Y$ are topological space then $y_0\in Y$ is the limit  of a function $f:X\to Y$ as $x$ approaches at the limit point $x_0\in X$  if and only if any net $\nu:\Lambda\to X\setminus\{x_0\}$ converging to $x_0$ is such that $f\circ\nu$ converges to $y_0$.

**Lemma**

If $\nu:\Lambda\to X$ is a net with values in a hausdorff space then it can converges at most one point.

Proof. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743525/x-is-hausdorff-iff-a-net-converges-to-at-most-one-point/3743595#3743595).

**Theorem**

A function $f: X\rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces has at least one limit at any limit point when $Y$ is hausdorff.

Proof. So if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two distinct limit of the function $f$ as $x$ approaches at the limit point $x_0$ then the net $\big(f(x_\lambda)\big)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ converges to $y_1$ and $y_2$ for any net $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ so that by the preceding lemma the two points must be equal.

So we conclude that the limit of the function $\varphi$ as $h$ approaches to $0$ is unique and so the the complex derivative is well define.